# C# Trouble initializing class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to initialize a class like this:

```
DllInjector mInject = new DllInjector();
```

but DllInjector() gives me error: "is inaccessable due to its protection level"
So I looked through the class and saw it had a singleton:

```
public static DllInjector GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DllInjector();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

So how do I instantiate the class and use it?

Comment: Whoever wrote that class did not want an instance created, but rather use that singleton accessor instead

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `DllInjector.GetInstance` doesn't work for you?

Comment: non-invokable member cannot be used like a method, how do I use the singleton? I did this: DllInjector instance = DllInjector.GetInstance;

Comment: @enkryptor hmm, I did that but the class isn't functioning as supposed too, maybe there is something wrong with the class :/, here is the link to it: https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/701697-post1.html

Comment: Note that the posted method implementation of GetInstance is not thread safe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). If you need to use that in a multithread environment, you need to follow Microsoft's advice in the linked article.

Comment: @EscageNULL we need the bigger picture. What goal are you trying to achieve, what result do you expect and what do you get actually?

Comment: @enkryptor, the class is meant to inject dlls into a process using createremotethread, unfortunately after calling inject and giving it the parameters, my dll fails to inject. Maybe the class doesn't support x64 :(

Answer (score 1):

The Singleton pattern implies you have only one single instance of the class.

So you can't just instantiate another one using the constructor:

```
var mInject = new DllInjector();
```

The constructor isn't public, that's why you get the  "is inaccessible due to its protection level" error. Instead, you are supposed to use the provided accessor to the existing instance:

```
var mInject = DllInjector.GetInstance;
```

If you call it for the first time, it will be instantiated automatically.

Comment: Thanks, still not getting the result from the class but thats another issue

Comment: By the way the implementation of singleton pattern is incorrect. You probably get different instances from different threads when `_instance` is not initialized. It's not thread-safe.

Comment: @EscageNULL - What does "still not getting the result from the class but thats another issue" mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Singleton is design pattern.**

**What does it mean :-**

It means you can only create one instance of a class and the constructor of that class is made private so it can not be instantiated from outside and actually the instance of that singleton is created within that class only and return using some properties or methods.

For more information you can check :-

[Implementing Singleton in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

And for deep dive you can go with one and only Jon Skeet

[Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)